# i want to add images to pdf from camera folder image show can i add a images in pdf

Tags: android, image, pdf, android-image

i am creating the pdf by using Document class,after i am downloading the images from sdcard camera folder,i want to keep all the images in pdf file,i am taking document page is A4 sizes,i want to scale image with A4 size means i want keep image with a4 sizes images.

```
private void addImages(Document document) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

        File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {


            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            thumbnails = decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

            ExifInterface exif;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());

                String orientString = exif
                        .getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);

                int orientation = orientString != null ? Integer
                        .parseInt(orientString)
                        : ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
                int rotationAngle = 0;

                if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                    System.out.println("photopotart");
                    thumbnails = getResizedBitmap(thumbnails, 150, 150);
                    thumbnails
                            .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                    Image myImg = null;
                    try {
                        myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

                    } catch (BadElementException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    // add image to document
                    try {
                        document.newPage();
                        document.add(myImg);
                    } catch (DocumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                    System.out.println("180 angle");
                    rotationAngle = 180;

                    System.out.println("photo180");
                    thumbnails = getResizedBitmap180(thumbnails, 200, 200);
                    thumbnails
                            .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                    Image myImg = null;
                    try {
                        myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

                    } catch (BadElementException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    myImg.setAlignment(Image.LEFT);

                    // add image to document
                    try {
                        document.newPage();
                        document.add(myImg);
                    } catch (DocumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                    System.out.println("other 270");

                    System.out.println("photo270");
                    thumbnails = getResizedBitmap270(thumbnails, 200, 200);
                    thumbnails
                            .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                    Image myImg = null;
                    try {
                        myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

                    } catch (BadElementException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                    // add image to document
                    try {
                        document.newPage();
                        document.add(myImg);
                    } catch (DocumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("photolandscape");

                    System.out.println("photo0");
                    // thumbnails =thumbnails.createScaledBitmap(thumbnails,
                    // 350, 250, false);
                    System.out.println("thumbnailsw" + thumbnails.getWidth());
                    System.out.println("thumbnailsh" + thumbnails.getHeight());


                    String imageUrl = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    Image image2 = Image.getInstance(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    image2.scaleAbsolute(150f, 150f);
                      document.newPage();
                      document.add(image2);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BadElementException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: What API your using for PDF ?

Comment: i am using itextpdf-5.3.5.jar,develop to create a pdf

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
                         Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                         myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

                         //add image to document
                         document.add(myImg);
```

And for scaling the image if not fill on page

```
 Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(unscaledBitmap, wantedWidth, wantedHeight, true);
```

Also go through [this](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android-application/) it has a good explanation for scaling the bitmap

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher); i didnot take the drawable image i am taking image dirctly from sd card.then how can i add

Comment: Are you getting bitmap or your getting file object ?

Comment: yeah  thumbnails = decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: thumbnails is what bitmap  ? that what i am asking if answer is yes then just do this  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                         
                         thumbnails .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
                         Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                         myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);